# How to save an attachment from outlook programmatically?

Tags: outlook

Everyday i get an email with a `.xlsx` attachment at 8AM . I need my `outlook 2010` to save this attachment to a folder om my desktop . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Alt + F11` --> Open a new Module -->

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk (myItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
'change xxx to your folder's name
saveFolder = “c:xxx”
For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
myAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & “\” & myAttachment.DisplayName
Set myAttachment = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Then create a new rule to apply this script to your recepients